# Messed up environment variables in Centos 7

Tags: environment-variables, path, java

When I am running my maven build I am getting this error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/bin/bin/java
```

I have edited `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `/root/.profile` and `/root/.bashrc` files with this:

```
export M3_HOME=/usr/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M3_HOME

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *probably* want `JAVA_HOME` to be `/usr` (or whatever it's supposed to be, I'm not a Java user, but it's usually something like `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05`, i.e. pointing to a specific JDK subdirectory), and then `PATH` to include `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.